# Multiple stats commands are not allowed (Cloudwatch Logs Insights)

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

With AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights I am getting the clients with # of checks less than 50, executing the following query works and I get the following output

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| parse @message /clientId=(?<clientid>\w+)/
| stats count() as Checks by clientid | filter Checks<50
```

**clientid Checks**
clientA   13
clientB   45

Now I want to get the sum of the checks that match the filter, here is the expected output

**sum(Checks)**
58

I tried the following query, but I am getting an error.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| parse @message /clientId=(?<clientid>\w+)/
| stats count() as Checks by clientid | filter Checks<50 | sum(Checks)
```

*Compile Error - Multiple stats commands are not allowed*